# Creating session in JDBC java

Tags: java, database, oracle, session, plsql

I have 2 method in a class.

By calling first method I am inserting data into `GTT(Global temporary table)`. Once data got inserted i am reading data from GTT by calling `another method` to create file. But I am not getting any data. does `session` gets closed if you come out of method? Means if you are inserting data in GTT by calling one method, I am not getting data of same table in another method. Is it possible in java? I have to use GTT Because of existing architecture in DB.

I am inserting data into GTT by calling below method.

```
public int insertDataToGTT(String p_entity_name, String p_update_mode) throws Exception
    {
        
        CallableStatement statement = 
                               connection.prepareCall("{call update_dynamic_entity_NEW(?,?)}");
        statement.setString(1, p_entity_name);
        statement.setString(2,p_update_mode);
        int numberOFRows=statement.executeUpdate();
        return numberOFRows;
    }
`update_dynamic_entity_NEW` procedure inserts data into `dynamicentitygtt` table.
```

Now I am reading same table in below method. Both the method in same class.

```
public  String createJsonFile(String dynamicEntityName) throws Exception
   {

    String query="select * from dynamicentitygtt";
    PreparedStatement prepstatement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs=prepstatement.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    { 
      //I am reading data here. But query is not returning any rows.
   }
```

Is there anyway if I insert data in one method and read same in another method of same class in GTT.

My GTT is `on commit preserve rows.`

Comment: Both methods using same connection? Data in GTT is private to the same session.(I'm no Java expert)

Comment: Could you show your code how you call these two methods ?